# Spring Boot + Apache Reverse Proxy: This combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot, ssl

What I have:

- I have a Spring Boot app as a docker image in a private registry
- SSL Certificate from Let's Encrypt

I ran this commands:

- `wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto`(get certbot)
- `chmod a+x certbot-auto` (make it exec)
- `./certbot-auto` (run it)
- `openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname root` (convert to Spring boot compatible keys)

In my Spring Boot app, I added this entries to the properties:

```
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store={key_store_location}
server.ssl.key-store-password={key_store_password}
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

At this point I can access my app through: https://example.com:8080/ and the certificate is valid.

Then I do this:
My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName {domain}

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 # Disable SSL versions with POODLE vulnerability

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8080/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

After I start apache2 and open https://example.com/ I get

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

*But*, if I enter https://example.com:80/ everything works.

So my question is: what do I need to do to get rid of the port and just get https://example.com/ to work?

Thank you.

EDIT: After I added 443 as suggested, the issue remains with the same error.

Full configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8080/


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:443>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8080/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Https port is 443. Could you please created SSL VirtualHost for 443 and add all entry inside VirtualHost and test.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
Listen 443 https
<VirtualHost Apache-IP:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName {domain}

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 # Disable SSL versions with POODLE vulnerability

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8080/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! the result is still the same, unfortunately. I made the changes and restarted apache.

Comment: share the latest configuration and error log for review.

Comment: I updated my original post with the information requested. Thanks!

Comment: Please remove SSL configuration from `<VirtualHost *:80>`.Restart Apache httpd and test.

Comment: I commented everything starting with SSL (6 lines in total) from the `<VirtualHost *:80>` portion of the config file and still the same error. http redirects correctly to https though

Comment: Share your error and access log entry for review. Also, don't forget to update the latest configuration.

Comment: I checked both error and access log. There are no entries that implies errors. Latest entry in access log is my own attempt to load the Spring Boot app

Comment: are you using any other SSL VirtualHost in Apache httpd? If yes then comment out and test. Also, let me know which URL are you accessing in the browser before and after redirection?

Comment: When creating the certbot certificate, a few files were created. After deleting those files in the config file, I was able to access the website properly. Thank you very much for pointing me to my error!!